# Elasticsearch does not respond with huge data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on centos5 and I run elasticsearch with version 1.0.0 with *-Xms808m -Xmx808m -Xss256k* parameters. There are 17 index and total 30200583 docs. Each index's docs count between 1000000 and 2000000. I create request query like ( each index have date field );

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "to": "2014-06-01 14:14:00",
              "from": "2014-04-01 00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": "50"
}
```

It give response;

```
{
   took: 5903
   timed_out: false
   _shards: {
      total: 17
      successful: 17
      failed: 0
   },
   hits: {
   total: 30200583
...
...
...}
```

However when I send query on elasticsearch-head tool for last 50 rows like;

```
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  "from": 30200533,
  "size": "50"
}
```

It does not give a response and throw exception like;

```
ava.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.copyBytes(DataOutput.java:247)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Directory.copy(Directory.java:186)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreDirectory.copy(Store.java:348)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.copy(TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:50)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.createCompoundFile(IndexWriter.java:4596)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.sealFlushedSegment(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:535)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.flush(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:502)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.doFlush(DocumentsWriter.java:506)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flushAllThreads(DocumentsWriter.java:616)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:370)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:285)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:260)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:250)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:170)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.XSearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(XSearcherManager.java:123)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.XSearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(XSearcherManager.java:59)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.XReferenceManager.doMaybeRefresh(XReferenceManager.java:180)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.XReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(XReferenceManager.java:229)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.refresh(InternalEngine.java:730)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.refresh(InternalIndexShard.java:477)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard$EngineRefresher$1.run(InternalIndexShard.java:924)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What is the problem? Is it not enough java heap space or does my query cause this heap space error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "yes".  You do not have enough heap space which is why you see the error, and the query caused the error because you don't have enough heap space.

The reason is because sorted, deep pagination is very expensive.  To retrieve the 20th element, you need to keep elements 1-20 in-memory and sorted.  To retrieve the 1,000,000th element, you need to keep elements 1-999,999 in-memory and sorted.

This often requires a considerable amount of memory.

There are a few options:

- Get more memory.  Problem solved
- Use [scan/scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) instead of a normal search. Scan/scroll does not perform scoring, so no sort order needs to be maintained, which makes it very memory efficient
- Use a different sorting criteria (e.g. reverse sort) or a smaller window (e.g. smaller range of dates so you can page to the end)